# HTML Section Link on an other HTML-Side

Tags: html

I have two html pages, like `index.html` and `contact.html`. On the pages i have the same navbar.

Can i link from `contact.html` to a section on `index.html`?

like `href="index.html#section"`, something like this!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to link to an element on `index.html` from `contact.html`. You can do this by creating an anchor tag (`<a>`) and setting its `href` to `index.html#elementId`.

```
<a href="index.html#someElementId">
```

Comment: i want to jump to a section on the index.html from contact html. i tried this <li><a href="index.html#comp">Unser Unternehmen</a></li> but i just get the index.html not the section with the id "comp"

Comment: If you want to go to an element on another page, add the element's `id` after a `#` in the URL. In the example above, it will automatically scroll down to the element with the `id` "someElementId".

Comment: If your page does not have any scroll, then it will not jump down. An example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40644557/html-section-link-on-an-other-html-side/40644604#comment68521167_40644604

Comment: How can i add the scroll?

Comment: You need to have more elements on your page, or you can add a large blank `div` under everything which will create a large blank space that will add a scroll.

Comment: Make sure you have the correct id. It should be `<div id="comp">`.

Comment: <section id="lief" class="rahmen"> thats it

Comment: Sorry i copied the wrong one.. it was <section id="comp" class="rahmen">.. and it does not work :(

Comment: This is because you're only linking to `#comp`, instead of `index.html#comp`. What you did is linking to a `#comp` on `contact.html`, instead of `index.html`.

Comment: Nono i linked the right one..  <li><a href="index.html#comp">Unser Unternehmen</a></li>